# how to connect a netlify function to my angular app

Tags: angular, netlify, faunadb

I'm unable to do a create request of form datas with a netlify function on my angular app

I'm trying to apply this tutorial https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/07/09/building-serverless-crud-apps-with-netlify-functions--faunadb/ on my project with angular7 front.

my netlify function:

```
/* code from functions/todos-create.js */
import faunadb from 'faunadb' /* Import faunaDB sdk */

/* configure faunaDB Client with our secret */
const q = faunadb.query
const client = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET
})

/* export our lambda function as named "handler" export */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  /* parse the string body into a useable JS object */
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body)
  console.log("Function `todo-create` invoked", data)
  const todoItem = {
    data: data
  }
  /* construct the fauna query */
  return client.query(q.Create(q.Ref("classes/todos"), todoItem))
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("success", response)
    /* Success! return the response with statusCode 200 */
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response)
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error", error)
    /* Error! return the error with statusCode 400 */
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(error)
    })
  })
}
```

my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Mission } from 'src/app/shared/models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MissionService {

  public mission = new Mission();
  myTodo = {
    title: 'My todo title',
    completed: false,
  };

  constructor() { }

  createTodo(data) {
    return fetch('/.netlify/functions/todos-create', {
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    });
  }
}
```

as requested in tutorial I add this at the end of my package.json:

```
"proxy": {
    "/.netlify/functions": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4200",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/\\.netlify/functions": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

but with "http://localhost:4200" adress for angular I supposed

I apply createTodo on click my form button but:

> "ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: JSON.parse:
>   unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" in firefox

AND

> "Request from ::ffff:127.0.0.1: POST /todos-create  Response with
>   status 500 in 12 ms.  Error during invocation:  TypeError: n is not a
>   function" in console

solution is here: https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/64

Comment: Can you check the logs on Netlify for `todos-create.js`? Seeing where the output went wrong will help debug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at what is the event received by the netlify function. Looks like the body is not a JSON object as a string, as expected by JSON.parse. That would not be surprising given that a GET call does not have a body.